# $(x^4-49)$ Is this polynomial completely factored over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Is this polynomial completely factored over $\mathbb{C}$?

$(x^4-49)$ = $((x^2)^2 - 7^2)$ =
     $(x^2 + 7)(x^2 - 7)$

Thanks

Comment: No, it is not completely factored if you are using real or complex numbers.

Comment: What do you mean of **factoring to complex numbers**?

Comment: "Is this polynomial completely factored over $\Bbb C$?" has the same answer as "Did I factor this polynomial to factors of degree $1$?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because $\sqrt{7}$ and $i$ exists, so  $(x^2-7)=(x-\sqrt{7})(x+\sqrt{7})$ and $(x^2+7)=(x-i\sqrt{7})(x+i\sqrt{7})$. More generally, in $\mathbb{C}$ you can factorize until you get linear terms (only "$x$" and no "$x^n$", with $n>1$).

Comment: To learn more about that, look up the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @dcolazin Thanks

Comment: @Joe That doesn‘t help a lot. He must look up complex numbers and factorization of polynomials

Comment: @Fakemistake, a standard corollary of the fundamental theorem of algebra is that every polynomial of one variable with complex coefficients, of degree $n$, can be expressed as a constant times $n$ monomials of the form $(z-r_i)$, where the $r_i$ are the roots of the polynomial. I’ve ‘learned’ the fundamental theorem of algebra in a few different math classes, and that factorization corollary is always covered.

Comment: @Joe But the fundamental theorem of algebra and the factorization corollary doesn't tell you how you find the complete factorization. Thus the answer in the original post is NO! The next step in thinking is, when the answer is no, what you have to do, such that the answer is YES. How do you find the factors of $x^2+7$ and $x^2-7$. And this is where I am. And as I've already said, the fundamental theorem of algebra and that corollary doesn't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to factor the polynimal over $R$, you have: $$x^4-49=(x^2)^2-49=(x^2-7)(x^2+7)=(x-\sqrt{7})(x+\sqrt{7})(x^2+7)$$ Over $C$, instead: $$x^4-7=(x-i\sqrt{7})(x+i\sqrt{7})(x-7)(x+7)$$